# WHERE not work in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I try this query in PhpMyAdmin:

```
INSERT INTO t1 ( col1, col2 )
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
FROM t2
WHERE (SELECT col3 FROM t1) = ANY (SELECT col3 FROM t2)
```

but given me that error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row !

anyone can fix it?

Comment: insert query is missing values keyword and parameter

Comment: @raheelshan `INSERT () SELECT ...` is valid SQL, there is no `VALUES` missing. As dasblinkenlight pointed out the error lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WHERE` condition is not correct, because it tries to compare a single value to a set; this is precisely what the error is trying to tell you.

Try this instead:

```
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from t1 t1j join t2 t2j on t1j.col3=t2j.col3)
```